# Identification of marking on capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification

Understanding markings as a beginner.
I am getting educated on what electronic items do. I have no experience and want to learn. I was not able to find the info I am looking for on the general web.

[image]

```
Nichicon   (manufacturer)
CE 105C    (temp range)
220 uf     (micro farad)
160 wv     (watt voltage) ?
GM(M)      (?)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the manufacturer documentation on their capacitors?

Comment: Not sure how to, part of education I need

Comment: One of the issues with things like MOSFETs & electrolytic capacitors is that if you have an older product it may be hard to find a datasheet because things progress. Currently Nichicon has about 20 different products listed in Digikey (some obsolete) that are 105°C 220uF 160V, they have different shapes, different life spans, different *minimum* temperatures, different ESR specifications and so on. None of them match the capacitor series GM(M). If the exact specs matter for your application you're better off to buy a current production part with a datasheet from a franchised distributor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CE 105\$^\circ\$C is the temperature rating, electrolytic capacitors generally come in either 85\$^\circ\$C or 105\$^\circ\$C ratings.

220 \$\mu\$F is the capacitance in micro-Farads.

WV is Working Voltage. This is the maximum continuous voltage that should be applied to the capacitor.

I believe GM(M) is the capacitor series which is manufacturer specific.

Comment: Thank you! so some of the capacitors in the series are GU(M) OR LQ(M) OR GN(M) ETC. Thats what confuses me

Comment: @MikeA You'd have to find a datasheet for the particular series. Usually the differences  between series are things like size, ESR, and lead free or not. Unless you have a requirement for some characteristic and are just using it in a hobby project it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: @MikeA *some of the capacitors in the series are GU(M) OR LQ(M) OR GN(M) ETC. That's what confuses me* They are just different models/types. All those letters are there for is to match up the tables in the datasheet to the part itself.